# Angular ag-grid combine Master/Detail with Row Pinning

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, master-detail

I am using Angular 10 together with ag-grid to create table. In my project I need to use expandable rows([Master/Detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/) feature) and row pinning ([Row Pinning](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-pinning/)). Both of these features are working well separately, but when row is pinned, it is impossible to expand it (chevron icon disappears). I've googled for the solution, but didn't find anything.
I've prepared stackblitz example, which reproduces my problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vkx5eq

I'll be grateful if you could tell me if my requirements can be achieved using ag-grid and provide working solution based on code example, which I've prepared.

Comment: Seems like row pinning doesn't work with master details as well